# Responsive layout: stretched images on Safari

Tags: html, css, image, scale, responsive

this is my layout.

The desired behavior is that when I resize the window vertically the image scales maintaining the original aspect ratio.

My code works very well in all browser **except Safari** (you can see it by trying the snippet in different browsers).

Do you have a solution? Thanks ;)

```css
.wrap-container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 55vh;
}

.wrap{
  width: 700px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.wrap img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex: 0;` on the image

```css
.wrap-container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 55vh;
}

.wrap{
  width: 700px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.wrap img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    flex: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```